# Media Query not working for min-height

Tags: html, css

I have an Image in my page. And I want it to have different height when screen height changes. My code is like this

```css
@media (min-height:  600px) {

    .focuspoint {
        min-height: 385px !important;
    }
      .focuspoint img{
        min-height: 385px !important;
    }
}

@media (min-height: 700px) {

    .focuspoint {
        min-height: 490px !important;
    }
       .focuspoint img{
              min-height: 490px !important;

    }
}

@media  (min-height: 800px) {

    .focuspoint {
        min-height: 450px !important;
    }
      .focuspoint img{
        min-height: 450px !important;
    }
}


@media (min-height: 900px) {

    .focuspoint {
        min-height: 685px !important;
    }
      .focuspoint img{
        min-height: 685px !important;
    }
}

@media  (min-height: 1050px) {

    .focuspoint {
        min-height: 985px !important;
    }
      .focuspoint img{
      min-height: 985px !important;
    }
}


@media (min-height: 1200px) {

    .focuspoint {
        min-height: 985px !important;
    }
     .focuspoint img{
        min-height: 985px !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<li class="panel activePage">
  <div class="focuspoint"  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <img src="/media/41661/1600x1070.jpg" class="img-responsive" >
  </div>

</li>
```

Every thing looks okay to me, But when I tested the media query is not taken by browser. Can any one please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reverse the order of your media queries, and also add both "min-height" and "max-height" to ensure that it renders correctly.

```
@media (min-height: 1200px) {

    .focuspoint {
        min-height: 985px !important;
    }
     .focuspoint img{
        min-height: 985px !important;
    }
}


@media  (min-height: 1050px) and (max-height: 1199px) {

    .focuspoint {
        min-height: 985px !important;
    }
      .focuspoint img{
      min-height: 985px !important;
    }
}

@media (min-height: 900px) and (max-height: 1049px) {

    .focuspoint {
        min-height: 685px !important;
    }
      .focuspoint img{
        min-height: 685px !important;
    }
}

@media  (min-height: 800px) and (max-height: 899px) {

    .focuspoint {
        min-height: 450px !important;
    }
      .focuspoint img{
        min-height: 450px !important;
    }
}

@media (min-height: 700px) and (max-height: 799px) {

    .focuspoint {
        min-height: 490px !important;
    }
       .focuspoint img{
              min-height: 490px !important;

    }
}


@media (min-height:  600px) and (max-height: 699px) {

    .focuspoint {
        min-height: 385px !important;
    }
      .focuspoint img{
        min-height: 385px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Athul Are you sure you want to rely on height? You generally rely on the media width for screen sizes. Try change all the "heights" in the media queries to "width."